# Cannot read last line of file, loop is not entered

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am trying to read in a .txt file into java. Regardless if it ends on a blank line or not, the reader will not read in the last line, and the program won't terminate.

```
public static ArrayList<String> readInput() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


//      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
//          String line = scanner.nextLine();
//          if (line.equals("") || line.isEmpty()) {
//                break;
//            }  
//           input.add(line);
//           System.out.println(line);
//      }
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {

                input.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not found or is unreadable.");
        }finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //PROGRAM WILL NOT GO BEYOND THIS POINT.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File has finished reading.");
         return input;
```

Here, I tried two methods. One with a buffered reader, and the other with a scanner, but neither works. Here is a snippet of the .txt file:

```
...some more lines...
33
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
34
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
35
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
36
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
```

The program will read up to the second last line. So this'll be what i see:

```
...some lines...
0 0 1
36
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

and the program will still be running. It won't even re-enter the while loop (i tested it with a println).

Even if i was to add a blank line after the last line like so:

```
...some lines...
0 0 1
36
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
<a blank line>
```

The program will read up to the last line of numbers, be unable to re-enter the loop, and the program will not terminate.

```
...some lines...
0 0 1
36
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
```

I've tried looking everywhere for solutions but can't seem to find one that actually solves this issue.

Preferably, I would like to follow scenario 1 where I do **not** end the text file with a blank line.

also each line of the .txt file ends on a new line, and contains no trailing white spaces.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens, if you remove !line.isEmpty() in the while-loop?

Comment: @RalfRenz nothing changes

Comment: You **say** that you're trying to read a file, but you read `System.in`. How do you *run* your code? Also: don't open *both* a `Scanner` **and** a `InputStreamReader` on the same underlying `InputStream` (`System.in`), that's bound to cause problems.

Comment: @JoachimSauer im running the text file through command line argument. Since im using eclipse, i set the run configuration to receive "test.txt", which is my file. Also, yes I forgot to comment that line out when running the buffered reader, but it doesn't seem to improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need an EOF character in order for your program to terminate. Try typing CTRL-D in your console, that will end the execution.

Comment: What counts as an EOF character? And why can't it read the last line? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what remains unclear to you. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file. I tested your method and it worked for me, I simply had to type CTRL-D and the last line popped up.